# HTML5 Video Won't Play on iPhone though FancyBox 2.0.4

Tags: jquery, iphone, fancybox, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video loaded into a hidden div that is called up through an image click with a FancyBox 2.0.4.  I have successfully got the HTML5 video to work with FancyBox through almost any browser on desktops, mac and pc (even ie). However with the iPhone (I dont know about android) the video appears to load however when you click the play button nothing happens.  I know the video works with iOS because when you link to it directly it plays no problem.

I call up the video with this line of code:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="#movie"><img src="images/sm/dm_rollover.jpg" alt="" name="Image1" width="175" height="175"></a>
```

and the video code:

```
<video id="movie" width="900" height="506" preload controls>
<source src="video/Demo.m4v"/>
<source src="video/Video/Demo.mov" type="video/mp4"/>
```

I know the iPhone wont play video larger then 640×480, I am using a reference movie (the .mov) to get around this issue allowing quicktime auto-select between an iPhone compatible version and the full-size video.

can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?
http://danielmease.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if this is the reason of your issue but you got this js error

```
Error: video is null
Source File: http://danielmease.com/
Line: 120
```

I assume because you have this script

```
<script>
 var video = document.getElementById('video');
 video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
 },false);
</script>
```

you are trying `getElementById('video')` when you don't have any selector with `id="video"`. According to your code, it should be `getElementById('movie')`, shouldn't be?

Normally other js errors can break the fancybox js code

Comment: thanks, i did forget that i changed the id, but thats not the problem.

i commented out that script and still nothing.  i wrote a new page with just fancybox, and the video and still nothing.  if i comment out fancybox and make the video div visible, it plays great, but when its called up though fancybox it just wont play.

danielmease.com/iphonealpha.html   -  video and fancybox

danielmease.com/iphonebrovo.html   -  just video

and this is only on iOS that i am finding this problem - decktops work fine everytime